# Could someone explain me the .getClass() method in java

Tags: java, object, methods, types, return

I am currently taking a java class in university. This is my first programming class and I've stumbled on something that I just cannot understand. As i learned, there are two ways of comparing variables. The first is using the `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>` , `=<` , `>=`  signs for PRIMITIVE variables such as int,double,etc. and the second way is to use the .equals() method for reference type. Now here is my question:

When I use the `.getClass()` method, I can compare two classes with the .equals() method and the `==` / `!=` method. Since I can use the `==`/`!=` signs, I'd suppose that the `.getClass()` method which returns the class of an object must return a primitive type. But searching on google the only thing I found out about this method in the java API is that it returns the class of an object. It doesn't tell me the variable type it returns. How exactly does this method work. What does it return? I tried to ask my teacher but she didn't know. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to know how `==` and `!=` compare the two operands. The reason why `==` and `!=` cannot be used to compare reference types is that they actually compare the *memory addresses* of the two reference type variables.

So if I have two strings:

```
String x = "Hello";
String y = x;
```

Since `x` and `y` share the same memory address after the second line is executed, `x == y` evaluates to true.

The same goes for the `getClass()` method. The `getClass()` method returns the class of the object as a `Class<T>` object. The question is, why this evaluates to true:

```
x.getClass() == y.getClass()
```

The answer is simple. Because `x` and `y` are both of type `String`. So calling `getClass` will return the same instance. This means the two returned the objects share the same memory address.

"But when I compare strings with the same characters with the `==` operator, it evaluates to false!" you shouted.

This is because the strings are located at different memory addresses. But the classes that `getClass` will return is always at the same memory address if the class that they represent is the same. This is due to the way `ClassLoader` works. But I'm not an expert that.

**You just need to know that the objects returned by getClass is at the same memory address if the classes they represent are the same.**

Answer (score 3):

The comparators `==` and `!=` compare equality in the way of identity. So how this works for primitives is obvious. However it can also be used to compare objects. However most often this does not work as expected. There are some exceptions:

`String`s are stored as literals, therefore if you define two instances of `String` containing the same value, they use the same literal. Think of this like both instances pointing to the same memory location.

`Enum`s are basically a collection of constants, therefore an enum value is either the same instance or it is not. It cannot be that the enum has the same value but is another instance.

The same is true for `Class` objects, which is what you get when calling `getClass()`. A `Class` object is created by the `ClassLoader` the first time it is the *.class file is loaded. On subsequent calls the same `Class` object is used. Therefore `Class` objects may be compared with `==` and `!=`. However beware that if `A.class` is loaded by two different `ClassLoader`s, the class objects that you get returned from them are not of the same instance.

Comment: _"Strings are stored as literals, therefore if you define two instances of String containing the same value, they use the same literal."_ this is wrong, this only applies for the same string literals or interned strings, not for **all** strings with the same value, example: `new String("X") != "X"`

Answer (score 0):

`getClass()` returns an instance (object) of the `Class` class. Since each Java class has a single instance of the `Class` class, if two objects belong to the same class, `getClass()` for those two objects will return the same isntance and therefore you can use `==` for comparing them, since `==` when applied to reference types determines if the two references refer to the same instance.

Comment: Don't forget about the `ClassLoader`, see hotzst's answer.

Comment: I would just like to thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly, each class creates a unique instance (object) of the Class class. Then when you use the getClass() method, it returns the reference to that class instance. This way, when you are using the != and == you are comparing the two different classes to see if they point to the same reference in the memory. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

The .getClass method will just return the class of the object. When you declare a new instance of an object, it will be referring to a class. There can only be one class per jvm but multiple object referring to it. So when you get the class of two objects, they might be referring to the same class!

Answer (score -2):

polymorphism is one of the most important feature for java. for example:

```
//this shows one use of getclass method.

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        Human human = new Human();
        m.dosomething(animal);//print animal
        m.dosomething(human);//print human
    }

    private void dosomething(Animal an){
        System.out.println(an.getClass().toString());
        }

    }

class Human extends Animal{

    private void dance(){
        }
}

class Animal{

    private void eat(){
        }
}
```